# backtrack 5 r3 packages are not downloading in terminal

Tags: package-management, backtrack

Here is some of the code, which it continues like this:

```
Err http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main liblaunchpad-integration1 0.1.35
  Could not resolve '32.repository.backtrack-linux.org'
Err http://32.repository.backtrack-linux.org/ revolution/main gedit 2.30.3-0ubuntu0.1
  Could not resolve '32.repository.backtrack-linux.org'
```

**Note**: This is when I run the apt-get install gedit command in the console as root

Comment: This is when i run the apt-get install gedit command in the console as root

Answer (score 0):

The messages you post seem to be BackTrack saying that it cannot find the server.

> Could not resolve '32.repository.backtrack-linux.org'

About a year ago, there was an announcement that BackTrack is no longer maintained, since the creators had moved on to Kali. I didn't see exactly what "no longer maintained" means but it is completely possible it means also no longer running the servers and hosting the files that your `apt-get` commands need in order to run.

Their home page mentions BackTrack no longer being maintained:

> Note: BackTrack Linux is no longer being maintained. Please check [www.kali.org](http://www.kali.org/)